# MySQL/MariaDB What is Prepare On Slow Log?

Tags: mariadb

I am using MariaDB 10.* on AWS RDS along with replica for read-only. I have enabled slow query and I notice there is a query that takes a lot of time. The `sql_text` is `Prepare` like the image below.

What is this? And how do I improve query so that I can get rid of this slow query? (I am currently experiencing latency on the service; often 502 Bad Gateway)

[image]

Columns are query_time, lock_time, rows_sent, rows_examined, and sql_text.

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There seems to be something missing from your question. What did you see in the slow query log?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have posted image.